# SQL Server: SELECT row once only where two values are the same

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery, common-table-expression

I'm working on an **OpenSource** and **free database** provided by [IP2Location](http://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone) that lists tons of IP addresses from internet.

You can download it from [here](http://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone).

My main interest aren't IP addresses: I want to have 1 geographical coordinate for each city per country.

The query I have now returns me doubles:

```
WITH cte AS
(   
    -- Let's pass rows that have the same latitude and longitude
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY latitude, longitude 
                            ORDER BY latitude, longitude) AS rn
    FROM ip2location_db11
    -- Avoid rows without city name
    where city_name != '-'          
)

SELECT
-- These are the only columns I'm interested in from the whole ip2location_db11 database
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY country_code desc,city_name desc) as countdown_order,
latitude,longitude,city_name,country_code
FROM cte
-- Let's take the first row where latitude and longitude are the same
WHERE rn = 1
-- I want to order results by city name
order by countdown_order desc
```

Which is very annoying:

[image]

One row with one **latitude** and **longitude** per city will be fine: I just want to put a pin on a map

Comment: Just use row_number() over(partition by city_name order by countdown_order) Then you will only get 1 row per city - do it in  a outer select of the current query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** If you can have the same city in different country_code, you just write that into the partition by as well. Otherwhise it should be something like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(   
    -- Let's pass rows that have the same latitude and longitude
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY latitude, longitude 
                            ORDER BY latitude, longitude) AS rn
    FROM ip2location_db11
    -- Avoid rows without city name
    where city_name != '-'          
)
,columnsneeded as (

SELECT
-- These are the only columns I'm interested in from the whole ip2location_db11 database
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY country_code desc,city_name desc) as countdown_order,
latitude,longitude,city_name,country_code
FROM cte
-- Let's take the first row where latitude and longitude are the same
WHERE rn = 1
)

Select countdown_order,latitude,longtitude,city_name,country_code 
from(
Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by city_name order by countdown_order) as rn1 from columnsneeded
)x where rn1 = 1
-- I want to order results by city name
order by countdown_order desc
```

Comment: I particularly liked your query because it makes the job done exactly as I wanted. And it just takes 9 seconds to execute. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, whether your first column (`countdown_order`) has any significance, or just a unique identifier for the row...

Anyway, if you just want to have a city/country with a pair of co-ordinates, you probably should use `GROUP BY` with the `AVG()` aggregate function to average the co-ordinates of the given city...

```
SELECT AVG(latitude) AS latitude, AVG(longitude) AS longitude, city_name, country_code
FROM ip2location_db11
GROUP BY country_code, city_name
ORDER BY country_code, city_name
```

Comment: Even if your query isn't exactly what I wanted I really appreciated the `AVG()`. I think it is a genius idea even if the query execution is slow (> 40 sec). Thank you, you teach me something today

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use `ROW_NUMBER` partitioned by city (and ordered by anything :)) and take only those equal to one in outer query (which you have to wrap around yours). Try this :

```
SELECT countdown_order,latitude,longitude,city_name,country_code FROM (
    SELECT
    -- These are the only columns I'm interested in from the whole ip2location_db11 database
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY country_code desc,city_name desc) as countdown_order,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city_name ORDER BY latitude) rnTofilter,
    latitude,longitude,city_name,country_code
    FROM cte
    -- Let's take the first row where latitude and longitude are the same
    WHERE rn = 1
    -- I want to order results by city name
) a WHERE rnToFilter = 1
order by countdown_order desc
```

Comment: Hi @Michal, the query returns me `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'cte'.`. If I then change `FROM cte` to `FROM ip2location_db11` it returns me `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Invalid column name 'rn'.` And from there I don't know what to change. 
But I see what you want to do. Thank you for your help